# How to enable on Linux (Android) BSD compatible syscall restart on EINTR error (using flag SA_RESTART)

Tags: c, linux, signals, bsd

I want to ask OS to auto restart all system calls (like open, read, write, and etc...) on EINTR error in Linux(Android) like it work in BSD. I found [**sigaction**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) with **SA_RESTART** flag. Now if I understand correctly I should enable flag **SA_RESTART** for every signal handler in system except (**SIGKILL** and **SIGSTOP**) Here is my solution:

```cpp
    auto EnableBSDStyleSyscallRestartOnEINTR = [](int sig) -> bool {
        int status;
        struct sigaction act;

        status = sigaction(sig, nullptr, &act);
        if (status == -1) {
            LoggerError("error get sigaction for signal: %d", sig);
            return false;
        }

        if (act.sa_flags & SA_RESTART) {
            return true;
        }

        act.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;
        status = sigaction(sig, &act, nullptr);
        if (status != 0) {
            LoggerError("can't update sigaction for signal: %d", sig);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    const auto listOfSignals = {
            SIGHUP,
            SIGINT,
            SIGQUIT,
            SIGILL,
            SIGTRAP,
            SIGABRT,
            SIGIOT,
            SIGBUS,
            SIGFPE,
            // SIGKILL - do not use with sigaction http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html
            // SIGUSR1
            SIGSEGV,
            // SIGUSR2
            SIGPIPE,
            SIGALRM,
            SIGTERM,
            SIGSTKFLT,
            SIGCHLD,
            SIGCONT,
            // SIGSTOP - do not use with sigaction http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html
            SIGTSTP,
            SIGTTIN,
            SIGTTOU,
            SIGURG,
            SIGXCPU,
            SIGXFSZ,
            SIGVTALRM,
            SIGPROF,
            SIGWINCH,
            SIGIO,
            SIGPWR,
            SIGSYS,
            SIGSWI
    };
    bool all_good = true;
    for (int sig : listOfSignals) {
        all_good &= EnableBSDStyleSyscallRestartOnEINTR(sig);
    }
    assert(all_good);
```

Is my solution correct? My be any more easy or elegant solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, you know that signals and signal handlers are very specific to the current process, and that you can't change the signal behavior of other unrelated processes? Secondly, *why* do you want to do this? What is the *real* problem you want to solve? And wouldn't it be easier to just fix it by setting the `SA_RESTART` flag when the process signal handlers are being initialized?

Comment: My application use a lot of networking and filesystem downloading and updating files so I decide to set in one place (start of app) enable SA_RESTART like in BSD and forget about it. I think it simpler, then check every file open, read, write in all my code and libraries.

Comment: Unless you set some signal handler before using the code you show, then none of the signal would have a handler. And the majority of the signals you list will *never* happen, ever, in your program. Properly set the signals *only* for the actual signals that can actually happen. Also, some of the signals you list will *kill* the process right of the bat, attempting to set the `SA_RESTART` flag for those is moot.

Comment: And for networking and working with pipes, the only signal you realistically need to handle is `SIGPIPE`, which your program should be set to *ignore* (and without the `SA_RESTART` flag as that's an error condition you need to explicitly handle). If you use the `alarm` function (or some other timers) then also handle `SIGALRM`. Possibly also `SIGCHLD` and `SIGTERM`/`SIGINT` depending on use-case and design and requirements.

Comment: I not set any signal handlers but may be some library I use set some. Tested my code on Android and it works some signal handlers already had ```SA_RESTART``` flag enabled, most not. Later I try at home play with this on my Fedora loading and storing large files and try to interrapt it with ```CTRL+C```